# Сочетаемость однородных сказуемых с подлежащим

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, сказуемые, однородные-члены

*И вот тут внятного ответа мы не получаем. Потому что никто не знает, или **знает** лишь поверхностно.*

"Никто знает" — нет ли грамматической ошибки?

P. S. Союз "или" присоединительный — с запятой всё в порядке.

Comment: По-моему, все наоборот: _сочетаемость однородных сказуемых с подлежащим._

Comment: Верно, опечатка.

Answer (score 2):

1. "Потому что никто не знает"(?!). Обычно пишут:"Потому что **этого** никто не знает".
   Неполная форма оправдана только в определенном контексте и с акцентом на *никто*. Например:

**Внятного ответа мы не получаем не потому, что кто-то знает этот предмет и молчит, а потому, что никто не знает.**

2. Если уж Вам хочется передать просоединительную интонацию, то вариант с запятой совсем плох. Используйте многоточие или точку.

**...потому что никто не знает... Или знает лишь поверхностно.**
**...потому что никто не знает. Или знает лишь поверхностно.**

"...никто не знает или знает лишь поверхностно"(?!). Спорная, скорее всего ошибочная конструкция. С каким подлежащим связано сказуемое *знает*? По-моему, придется удлинить предложение: 
**...никто не знает, а если кто и знает, то лишь поверхностно.**

Comment: Почему плох вариант с запятой в данном случае?
"С каким подлежащим связано сказуемое *знает*?" — с *никто*. Я и спрашиваю, есть ли грамматическая ошибка ("никто знает")? В этом как раз состоит мой вопрос.

Comment: На мой взгляд, нельзя так писать (никто знает?!)

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки стиля нужен контекст, для правильной  постановки знаков препинания нужен корректный стиль. Поэтому старайтесь по возможности давать связанный текст, из которого ситуация понимается однозначно.

**Потому что никто (этого) не знает или знает лишь поверхностно.**

Запятая не ставится между однородными сказуемыми (паузы нет). Сравнить: Она (этого) не знает или знает лишь поверхностно.

Пример: Даже если **он ничего не знает или знает какую-то малость,** он обязательно в разговоре эту малость ввернет, чтобы произвести впечатление человека знающего. [Протоиерей Димитрий Смирнов. Проповеди (1984-1989)]

Comment: Я вроде указал, что второй член имеет присоединительный характер, а значит есть пауза.

Comment: То есть то, что сказуемое "знает" относится к подлежащему "никто" — это нормально?

Comment: 1) С чего вы взяли, что ИЛИ имеет здесь присоединительный характер, этот союз разный характер может иметь, его семантика определяется предложением, а не желанием автора. 2) Все знают,  никто не знает - что здесь может быть неправильного? Мы не можем сказать: все не знают, вот это неправильная форма.

Comment: Но «все» в предложении нету.

Comment: Я думал, что автор может наделить любой член однородного ряда значением добавочного замечания и обособить соответствующе.

Comment: Автор может наделить, но читатель должен с ним согласиться. Вот примеры предложений с присоединительным союзом ИЛИ: Он вернулся в одиннадцать часов, или около этого. И детей оставили, или почти что оставили, в покое. Союз ИЛИ здесь не разделительный и не пояснительный, это видно из содержания предложений.

Comment: @Jasmin, Не нашел у Вас четкого ответа на вопрос. В этом предложении просматривается странная основа "никто знает". Разве так можно писать?

Comment: В русском языке отрицательные конструкции с местоимениями строятся особенным образом ( с усилительной частицей НИ): Кто знает? - Никто не знает.  В заданном предложении смысл такой: субъект (некто) этого не знает или знает поверхностно. При отрицании этот субъект  обозначается местоимением никто. Пример без запятой: ... человек, о прошлом которого никто не знает или, во всяком случае, не вспоминает. [Н. К. Гудзий. История древней русской литературы. (XVI-XVII вв.) (1938)]

Comment: В вашем примере оба сказуемых с отрицанием. В нашем же примере второе сказуемое не имеет отрицания относится к местоимению «никто».  Пример бы подошёл, если было бы: «...никто не знает, но воспоминает». С тем, что «никто» является отрицательной формой местоимения «некто», я не согласен. «Некто» — некий человек, кто-то (неопределенный, но конкретный), «никто» — ни один человек, отрицание какого-либо лица, не конкретного.